# Which is the right way to call an external API when and Orbeon form is validated

Tags: orbeon, nuxeo

I have created an Orbeon form with 5 fields:

- First name
- Second name
- e-mail
- Phone
- Case description

I want to call an external REST API ([Nuxeo: Updating a Document](https://doc.nuxeo.com/nxdoc/document-resources-endpoints/#updating-a-document)) when the form is validated.

Reading Orbeon documentation I don't find the right way to do this.

Based on the documentation found in [Orbeon Http Services](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-builder/http-services.html) it looks like it doesn't provide a way to customize the JSON that I must send in the API call with the form fields values.

Comment: Let's see: does the service validate all 5 fields? What does it return? Does it tell you which one is incorrect, or just that something is invalid in those fields?

Comment: This service must be called once the form has been validated. It will update the pre-existing information in Nuxeo

Comment: OK, so the service stores the data somewhere, or does some processing with the data, then you'll want to use the `send()` action. I'll elaborate on an answer below.

Comment: I followed-up with an answer below explaining the general mechanism, with links to the relevant documentation. You'll let me know if this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the general idea:

1. You can setup what button you want to have at the bottom of your form ([doc](https://doc.orbeon.com/configuration/properties/form-runner-detail-page.html#buttons-on-the-detail-page)).
2. Each button, run a "process". A process is composed of a sequence of actions ([doc](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/advanced/buttons-and-processes/)).
3. One possible action is `send()`, which allows you to send the XML containing the data entered by users ("form data") to a service you provide ([doc](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/advanced/buttons-and-processes/actions-form-runner-send.html)).

With this, you can setup your form to have a "Send" button, which upon activation runs validation, saves the data, and sends it to your service.

Comment: This is one step in a more complex process:


  1. Create a document in Nuxeo
  2. Populate a form in Orbeon with the data collected (using the Orbeon API)
  3. Send an e-mail to the user with the Orbeon form previously created and populated
  4. The user modifies the data in the Orbeon form
  5. The information is sent to Nuxeo using Nuxeo REST API

 I'm stuck on step 5.


I must respect the Nuxeo REST API interface, so maybe a call using JQuery AJAX call is the most direct way to do this.

Comment: Are you by any chance working with Thierry Delprat? If not, you might be interested by the work he's doing on an [implementation of the persistence API for Nuxeo](http://discuss.orbeon.com/SPI-for-DataBinding-tp4663454p4663476.html).